# Is there a way to display png or tiff, instead of xpm, images on the Emacs toolbar for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, tool-bar

Is there an emacs version that supports displaying png / tiff images on the toolbar instead of only xpm?

On Mac the  Mitsuharu Yamamoto version display TIFF images without any issue. I tried modifying tool-bar.el to add the tiff and png support but did not work. The emacs version on windows is the GNU one with dependencies installed and  I can display PNG images in the buffer, the issue is only in the toolbar.

I was wondering if the image support for the toolbar is coded directly into the emacs code and that is why the GNU version does not recognize the modified tool-bar.el

Comment: I can't answer your question but I know that many (maybe most) Emacs users don't display the toolbar at all.